# I m not able to connect to mongo with a container docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I m new to docker 
so i followed up a tutorial [here](https://www.leeboonstra.com/developer/tutorial-full-stack-javascript-for-the-enterprise-getting-started-with-ext-js-node-js-express-mongodb-and-docker-6/) , part 6,7 and 8 in order to use and learn docker in a project.

The problem is that when i use docker-compose.yml to build images on my laptop,
my stack_server can connect to mongo.

**But if i build images from docker hub and i pull and run them seperately on my laptop,my stack_server CAN't connect to mongo.**

here is my docker-compose.yml :

```
client:
    build: ./client
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - server
mongo:
  image: mongo
  command: --smallfiles
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
server:
    build: ./server
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    links:
     - mongo
```

However, my stack_client can connect to the stack_server.

and my commands to run my image (my images are public)

```
docker-run -i -t -p 27017:27017 mongo
docker-run -i -t -p 80:80 mik3fly4steri5k/stack_client 
docker-run -i -t -p 8080:8080 mik3fly4steri5k/stack_server
```

and my error log

```
bryan@debian-dev7:~$ sudo docker run -i -t -p 8080:8080 mik3fly4steri5k/stack_server
[sudo] password for bryan: 
Express server listening on 8080, in development mode
connection error: { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1021:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1175:14)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017' }
```

here is my stack_server dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest

# Set in what directory commands will run
WORKDIR /home/app

# Put all our code inside that directory that lives in the container
ADD . /home/app

# Make sure NPM is not cached, remove everything first
RUN rm -rf /home/app/node_modules/npm \
 && rm -rf  /home/app/node_modules

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Tell Docker we are going to use this port
EXPOSE 8080

# The command to run our app when the container is run
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

## First Solution but deprecated

```
docker-run -i -t -p 27017:27017 --name:mongo mongo
docker-run -i -t -p 80:80 mik3fly4steri5k/stack_client 
docker-run -i -t -p 8080:8080 --link mongo:mongo mik3fly4steri5k/stack_server
```

I had to put a name on my mongo and to link it with the parameter --link when i run my stack_server

[docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#connect-using-network-port-mapping)

```
Warning: The --link flag is a deprecated legacy feature of Docker. 
It may eventually be removed. 
Unless you absolutely need to continue using it,
we recommend that you use user-defined networks to facilitate communication 
between two containers instead of using --link.
One feature that user-defined networks do not support that you can do with 
--link is sharing environmental variables between containers.
However, you can use other mechanisms such as volumes to share environment 
variables between containers in a more controlled way.
```

Comment: your mongo application is listening on 27017 instead of 8080 (ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017)

Comment: why my mongo application should listen 8080 ? mongo have to listen on its defaults port 27017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your stack_server with below command

```
sudo docker run -i -t -p 8080:8080 --link mongo:mongo mik3fly4steri5k/stack_server
```

Note: --link flag is a deprecated

Comment: what is the replacement of --link flag?

Comment: With --link parameter your functionality is working? You can follow the below link https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#connect-using-network-port-mapping

Comment: Great, glad to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

Your container is running. But is it healthy? I recommend that you implement Healthcheck

It’s actually would look pretty much the same:
(Docker-compose YAML)

```
healthcheck:
  test: curl -sS http://127.0.0.1:8080 || echo 1
  interval: 5s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 3
```

Docker health checks is a cute little feature that allows attaching shell command to container and use it for checking if container’s content is alive enough.

I hope it can help you.

more info https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#healthcheck

Comment: well cut little feature, but whats happens if healtcheck fails? can i have a callback cmd?

Answer (score 0):

To start MongoDB on a desire port you would have to do the followings:

```
client:
    build: ./client
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - server
mongo:
  image: mongo
  command: mongod --port 27017
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
server:
    build: ./server
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    links:
     - mongo
```

Comment: well i know that, when i use docker-compose.yml, all is working fine.
this is when i do not use docker-compose.yml that my stack_server can't connect to mongo !

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at error

> connection error: { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Server trying to connect to `localhost` instead of mongo. You need to configure server to connect mongo to `mongo:27017`

`mongo` is alias created by docker for linking containers to each other.

Comment: already tryied but not worked ( i will try again and come back )

Comment: Could you show me what exception do you obtain now?